# PowerMock verifyNew fails - No interations with this mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to verify the number of constructor calls using PowerMock. I have this test function below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({BaseWhereClauseItem.class})
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testDuplicateExists() throws Exception {
        ...
        when(client.execute(any(), any(), any(), any(QueryDefinition.class))).thenReturn(records);
        whenNew(BaseWhereClauseItem.class)
                .withParameterTypes(String.class, String.class, WhereActionType.class)
                .withArguments(any(), any(), any())
                .thenReturn(PowerMockito.mock(BaseWhereClauseItem.class));

        serviceUnderTest.create(view); // .create() is a wrapper function under test. The actually constructor call happens in the private method that is invoked in .create()
        verifyNew(BaseWhereClauseItem.class, times(4)).withArguments(any(), any(), any());

    }

}
```

The function being tested is here:

```
// The wrapper function around the private method under test
public void create(View view) throws Exception{

    boolean duplicateExists = checkDupilcateExists(view.getName(),         
    view.getType(), view.getDescription());

    if (duplicateExists) {
        ....
    }
}
```

```
private boolean checkDupilcateExists(String name, String type, String description) throws Exception {
    ...

    QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(Constants.VIEW.NAME, SelectList.of(Constants.ID));
    final List<WhereClauseItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // BEGIN: call constructor under test 
    items.add(new BaseWhereClauseItem(Constants.RECORD.NAME, EscapeUtil.escape(name), WhereActionType.EQ));
    items.add(new BaseWhereClauseItem(Constants.VIEW.FLD_CREATED_FOR, CommonValues.SYSTEM_USER_ID.toString(), WhereActionType.EQ));
    items.add(new BaseWhereClauseItem(Constants.VIEW.FLD_VIEW_TYPE, EscapeUtil.escape(type), WhereActionType.EQ));
    items.add(new BaseWhereClauseItem(Constants.VIEW.FLD_DESCRIPTION, EscapeUtil.escape(description), WhereActionType.EQ));
    query.setWhereClause(new WhereClause(new CompositeWhereClauseItem(items, WhereClause.LogicalOperator.AND)));
    // END: call constructor under test

    ResultSet resultSet = client.execute(query, ...); // execute this query
    if (resultSet.getSize() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why would PowerMock return:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Wanted but not invoked veeva.ecm.common.interfaces.web.contract.query.request.BaseWhereClauseItem(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I clearly called that constructor many times. I looked at examples to get familiar with syntax (https://www.javatips.net/api/org.powermock.api.mockito.powermockito.verifynew), but still no good.

Please help.

Comment: I would question the appproach of using powermock to mock the constructor calls. We could instead inspect the generated `List` and validate its entries. --- I would suggest to use `anyString()` instead of `any()` if we mock a `String`-parameter. --- Is this the whole test-code? If so: Where is the call to the system under test?  The test - as is - sets up the mock and immediately validates, which will obviously fail since the constructor war never called.

Comment: @Turing85, I could try that approach. It is just a bit difficult since I would be spying on a local variable (the List) created from a direct instantiation within this function, but I hear it's still possible.

Comment: @Turing85, I edited to make the constructor call part more explicit and added some more segments of the function under test.

Comment: I still fail to see where the sut/uut is called.

Comment: The call to the constructor iis only mocked, but I still fail to see where in the test the mocked method is actually **called**.

Comment: @Turing85, had to search up what `sut` meant, sorry. I added additional code above, particularly that call the the `create` method.

Comment: It is for sure called as I stepped through the code. At first, I just didn't want to reveal too much code at once as I have to change variables names to prevent "revealing too much" about the product, and I wanted to narrow the focus down to the important parts. Anyway, I updated :)